# Can a Spring JPA Entity implement a Projection interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

[Interface-based Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html#projections.interfaces) are a handy feature in Spring JPA, allowing a Repository to return different interfaces. For a simple example, this entity...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}
```

...can omit a field and result from a native query.

```
public interface EntityDTO {
    String getFoo();
    String getBar();
}

@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from entity where id = :id")
    EntityDTO findDtoById(int id);
}
```

The above works... unless I want the entity itself to implement the projection interface.

```
public class MyEntity implements EntityDTO
```

This relationship seems natural, since the entity does in fact implement the interface, and service methods shouldn't care whether they're reading from an entity or some other projection; but implementing the projection results in an exception from the query.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [EntityDTO]
```

Is there a way to make JPA proxy the `EntityDTO` as an unrelated interface, even when it is implemented by `MyEntity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface with the common methods (`getFoo()`, `getBar()`) and make both `EntityDTO` and `MyEntity` extend/implement it. Then you can use it as a type wherever entity itself (not interested in `id`) or its projection is provided.